# Smallest server setup for Raspberry Pi - scalability not important

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webserver, raspberry-pi

I'm building a system that manages home HVAC and uses a Raspberry Pi running Ruby on Rails 3.2 with Ruby 2.0.  Nearly all web content is dynamic.  Scalability is not important, as it's only used within a home network and by only one or two simultaneous users.  What's important is using minimal memory.  Reliability is also very important.  Fast is good.  Does it make sense to just use the default Webrick server in production, or is there value in fronting it with say Apache or Cherokee and/or replacing it with Passenger or Puma or something else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use use Webrick in production environments. It lacks support for handling concurrent requests and is optimized for development. Adding a fully blown webserver like Apache would not help you to reduce the memory.

I recommend to use **[Thin](http://code.macournoyer.com/thin/)** in your scenario. It's a fast and lightweight webserver written in Ruby.

Comment: Thin works great for me.  Simple and clear documentation too, exactly what I needed to know.  Thank you.

Comment: When using thin this way, you need to edit `config/environments/production.rb` to set `config.serve_static_assets` to true or else the precompiled assets in `public` won't get served by thin.